# ¿Cómo dejar los datos asociados en una sola tupla en bases de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, plsql

Nuestro maestro no entregó ningún enunciado (por eso la formulación de mi pregunta). Ejemplo: A Juan se le vendió una leche y va a quedar guardado en la base de datos, luego se le vendió un pan. Cuando se realiza la consulta en la tabla ventas, aparecen dos boletas por separado. Entonces, lo que quiere mi maestro es que cuando una persona compre los productos, que dichos productos queden asociados a una sola boleta.
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?
Adjunto código:

```
   CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
id_cliente INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
telefono VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO(
id_producto INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
descripcion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
precio INT NOT NULL
); 


CREATE TABLE VENTA(
id_venta INT  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
id_cliente INT,
id_producto INT,
FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE (id_cliente),
FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (id_producto)
); 

INSERT INTO CLIENTE 
VALUES ('Rodrigo Cabello','Vergara 165','+56912345678','Santiago');

INSERT INTO CLIENTE (nombre,direccion,telefono,ciudad) 
VALUES ('Felipe Silva','Direccion 123','+56987654321','Valparaiso');

INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES 
('Leche',750),
('Arroz',550);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES ('Pan',1290);

INSERT INTO VENTA VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO VENTA VALUES (2,1,2);

SELECT * FROM CLIENTE;
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO;
SELECT * FROM VENTA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso, necesitas crear una nueva tabla de detalle de ventas. Así mantienes una sola venta, pero puedes incluir todos los artículos que quieras. De esa forma, dejas todos los atributos de la venta en una tabla, y los atributos de los productos vendidos en otra tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    id_cliente INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO(
    id_producto INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    descripcion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    precio INT NOT NULL
); 


CREATE TABLE VENTA(
    id_venta INT  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    id_cliente INT,
    fecha date,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE (id_cliente)
); 

CREATE TABLE DETALLE_VENTA(
    id_venta INT NOT NULL,
    id_detalle INT NOT NULL,
    id_producto INT,
    cantidad INT,
    precio DECIMAL(12,4), --Se pone un precio porque el de la tabla productos puede cambiar pero no debe alterar las ventas previas.
    importe AS cantidad * precio,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_venta, id_detalle),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_venta) REFERENCES VENTA (id_venta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (id_producto)
)

INSERT INTO CLIENTE (nombre, direccion, telefono, ciudad)
VALUES ('Rodrigo Cabello','Vergara 165','+56912345678','Santiago'),
       ('Felipe Silva','Direccion 123','+56987654321','Valparaiso');

INSERT INTO PRODUCTO (descripcion, precio)
VALUES  ('Leche',750),
        ('Arroz',550),
        ('Pan',1290);

INSERT INTO VENTA (id_cliente, fecha)
VALUES (1, GETDATE())

INSERT INTO DETALLE_VENTA (id_venta, id_detalle, id_producto, cantidad, precio)
VALUES  (1, 1,1,1, 750),
        (1, 2,2,1, 550);


SELECT * FROM CLIENTE;
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO;
SELECT * FROM VENTA;
SELECT * FROM DETALLE_VENTA;
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!